# having error in WHERE clause of SQL query,

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am having an error in this code:

```
public List<AvailableTest> srchInTestsInDb(String search, String catg) {
    try 
     { 
         Connection conn = Dbconn.Connect();

         System.out.println(catg);

         String sql = "SELECT * "
                 + "FROM AVAILABLE_TESTS "
                 + "WHERE TST_CATAGORY="+catg+"";
                // + "TST_NAME LIKE '"+search+"%'";// AND TST_CATAGORY ="+catg+""; 

         Statement statement = conn.createStatement(); 
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql); 
         List<AvailableTest> testList = new ArrayList<AvailableTest>(); 
         while (rs.next()) 
         { 
            AvailableTest newtest = new AvailableTest(); 

            newtest.setTstNo(rs.getInt("TST_NO"));

            newtest.setTstName(rs.getString("TST_NAME"));

            newtest.setTstCatagory(rs.getString("TST_CATAGORY"));

            newtest.setTstNormalValue(rs.getString("TST_NORMALVAL"));

            testList.add(newtest); 
         } 
         return testList;
     } 
     catch (SQLException ex) 
     { 
         Logger.getLogger(DbHandeler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         return null; 
     }
}
```

Its output is:

```
chem
Jul 29, 2014 10:02:28 PM Db.DbHandeler srchInTestsInDb
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "CHEM": invalid identifier
```

When I print "catg" it prints "chem" which I need in my query, but it's not working.

Comment: I assume `TST_CATAGORY="+catg+"";` is a string... so shouldn't it be... `TST_CATAGORY='"+catg+"'";`

Comment: You aren't quoting the string you're passing in.  You can avoid that (among other things, like SQL Injection) by using parameterised queries.

Answer (score 4):

It should be `WHERE TST_CATAGORY='"+catg+"'"`, since a String parameter should be in quotes.

That said, that's a very bad practice, and you run the risk of SQL injection. Use a prepared statement :

```
String sql = "SELECT * "
                 + "FROM AVAILABLE_TESTS "
                 + "WHERE TST_CATAGORY=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString (1, catg);
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery ();;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is considering CHEM a column name since it isn't quoted.  To get Oracle to treat it as a string, use single quotes.

```
String sql = "SELECT * "
+ "FROM AVAILABLE_TESTS "
+ "WHERE TST_CATAGORY='"+catg+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String sql = "SELECT * "
                 + "FROM AVAILABLE_TESTS "
                 + "WHERE TST_CATAGORY='"+catg+"';";
```

Since the content of catg is a String it should also be in quotation marks (in the SQL-Query).